# AWS Amplify Build Issue - StackUpdateComplete

Tags: aws-amplify

When running `amplify push -y` in the CLI, my project errors with this message:

`["Index: 0 State: {\"deploy\":\"waitingForDeployment\"} Message: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete"]`

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete" is the message that comes from the root CloudFormation stack associated with the Amplify App ID. The Amplify CLI is just surfacing the error message that comes from the update stack operation. This indicates that the Amplify's CloudFormation stack may have been still be in progress or stuck.

**Solution 1 – “deployment-state.json”:**

To fix this issue, go to the S3 bucket containing project settings and deleted the “deployment-state.json” file in root folder as this file holds the app deployment states. The bucket should end with, or contain the word “deployment”.

**Solution 2 - CloudFormation Stack Not In `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE`**
Sometimes your stack will fail to `rollback` and thus be stuck. One example of this is when you try to update your DynamoDB tables' billing modes more than once via CI/CD. To fix this, go to your root stack, and click "Continue update rollback". When the status of your root stack is suffixed `_COMPLETE`, you should be able to try again.

**Solution 3 – “Requested resource not found”:**

Check the status of the CloudFormation stack and see if you can notice that the stack failed because of a “Requested resource not found” error indicating that the DynamoDB table “tableID” was missing and confirm that you have deleted it (possibly accidentally). Manually create the above DynamoDB table and retry to push again.

**Solution 4A - “@auth directive with 'apiKey':**

If you recieve an error stating that “@auth directive with 'apiKey' provider found, but the project has no API Key authentication provider configured”. This error appears when you define a public authorisation in your GraphQL schema without specifying a provider. The public authorization specifies that everyone will be allowed to access the API, behind the scenes the API will be protected with an API Key. To be able to use the public API you must have API Key configured.

The @auth directive allows the override of the default provider for a given authorization mode. To fix the issue specify “IAM” as the provider which allows to use an "Unauthenticated Role" from Cognito Identity Pools for public access instead of an API Key.

Below is the sample code for public authorisation rule:

```
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [create, read, update, delete] }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```

After making the above changes, you can run “amplify update api” and add a IAM auth provider, the CLI generated scoped down IAM policies for the "UnAuthenticated" role automatically.

**Solution 4B - Parameters: [AuthCognitoUserPoolId] must have values:**

Another issue could occur here, where the default authorization type is API Key when you run the command “amplify add api” without specifying the API type. To fix this issue, follow these steps:

1. Deleted the the API
2. Recreate a new one by specifying the “Amazon Cognito user pool” as the authorization mode
3. Add IAM as an additional authorization type
4. Re-enable @auth directive in the newly created API Schema
5. Run “amplify push”

**Documentation:**

1. [Public Authorisation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/auth/#public-authorization)
2. [Troubleshoot CloudFormation stack issues in my AWS Amplify project](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amplify-cloudformation-stack-issues/)

Answer (score 1):

I want to add something to the solution marked as correct, there is another case I found where this same error is showing. So I had too many changes in my GraphQL schema and I was trying to do amplify push, then also I ran into the same issue. So if you added multiple **@key** directives to you schema at the same time then also this same error may appear. So you can remove all your newly added **@key** and then try to add them one by one.

Hope it helps someone.

Reference:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/819

Answer (score 0):

I concur with @Brock002. If you are adding in new keys and indexes, or other changes to your schema with connections. You can get this error.  For example I had :

```
Event @model() {
id: ID!
//etc
volunteers: [Applicants]
}

Applicants @model() {
id: ID
etc
}
```

and I was trying to update it to:

```
Event @model() {
id: ID!
//etc
volunteers: [Applicants] @hasMany(indexName: "byApplicant", fields: ["id"])
}

Applicants @model() {
id: ID
//etc
 eventID: ID! @index(name: "byApplicant", sortKeyFields: ["id"])
 event: Event!  @belongsTo(fields: ["eventID"])
}
```

this didn't work. It hung out on deploying rootstack 4... for much longer than normal.

```
["Index: 0 State: {\"deploy\":\"waitingForDeployment\"} Message: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete"]
```

To fix this, i deleted the applicants table, and the volunteers:[applicants] field , by running:

```
 amplify push --allow-destructive-graphql-schema-updates
```

Then I reintroduced them into my schema I got another error: Create Applicants table failed - applicants exists :< - probably because I wrote a custom function that referenced that table.

I changed the name to Applicant (without the s) and added the annotations/indexes I wanted and it worked. I feel like the error message in question is thrown sometimes when you modify the schema and the "logical" steps the tools build the resources with are unable to complete, and it fails.